# Neural Network with different input shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm currently designing the architecture of a neural network for the colorization of grayscale images. Later on it should be able to colorize images with different sizes and different aspect ratios. I read that this would not be possible with a common CNN. I also read that the only options are downscaling the images to one specific size or to use a big fixed size (like 3000x3000px) and to fill the remaining space black. Both of these options don't seem to be that elegant. The first one is the opposite of what I want and the second would make the neural network slower.

Then I read about Fully Convolutional Networks and that this problem would not exist there. This would be great if it really works. I would like to know why this special network can deal with different input shapes. And maybe you could show me some tensorflow code of such a network.

By the way, I thought about an Autoencoder combined with a GAN for the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you cannot train any network with different sample size on the same batch.

Fully convolutional network is similar to a fully connected network with fully connected layers at the end. As such any input image in the batch must have the same dims (w,h,d).

The difference is that a fully connected layers output a single output vector for every sample in the input batch while the fully convolutional net outputs a map of probability for each class.

It has a deeper meaning than just the image size, when trying to fit any data the size of it must be absolute and cannot be changed while training. I guess you can do it in different batches as I stated but I've never tried it.

An encoder\decoder could help "rebuild" the image in a specific size.

This tip, again, is from my experience in object detection, I could be wrong :)

Comment: Thank you very much. So you think that it could work in theory if all images in a batch have the same size? Then, how would the decleration of the model look like when the number of neurons in a layer change from batch to batch? (in tensorflow)

Comment: Hey bro, This question obviously cannot be answered briefly, I did find this paper 
that layout the architechture of such network, regarding different image size per batch, I'm not sure if and how it can be done with TF. http://iizuka.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/projects/colorization/data/colorization_sig2016.pdf